# How to handle requests in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I explain my question using the following image.

[image]
 1. First user login to my app which hosted on server [3], via cloud[1].
    In the meantime, the user authenticates using Identity Provider[1].
    And Identity Provider sends JWT to Cloud Server[1].

2. Then Cloud Sercer[1] send the request to my Application Server[1]
   along with that JWT as request header and Application Server[3] then serve index page
   back to the user.

Now my problem is I need to get that JWT within my ReactJs application in order to get user details within that JWT. Since React is client-side framework I unable to handle requests with React.

So my problem is how can I get this JWT from ReactJs side?

Comment: why don't you response with json?

Comment: You mean that instead of passing JWT as header send it as JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ReactJS it self cannot handle this because it's frontend.

You need to have a separate backend for your application (i.e BFF - backend for frontend). You can use a nodejs server to wrap your frontend and have a middleware to capture the JWT request and extract user details. Then at the time of serving to react frontend from the nodejs server, you can bind the information to it.

When binding I would prefer binding data to a javascript variable or function.

in your react index page you can have a global function.

```
<body>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    function getUserDetails(){
      return JSON.parse("!!!!USER_DATA!!!!");
    }
  </script>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

and you can replace '!!!!USER_DATA!!!!' part with a valid json with user details when rendering the react page from BFF. like this,

```
let userDetailJsonString = JSON.stringify(dataFromJWT);
res.send(renderingIndexPage.replace(/\!\!\!\!USER_DATA\!\!\!\!/g, userDetailJsonString.replace(/"/g, "\\\"")));
```

You can do this in different ways, You may try a  different way.